# How to select a td that has class "foo"?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, html-table

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack and I'd like to select the value from inside the td with class `title`.  I need the value `Battlefield 3` which is inside the `<a>` tag.

I've tried the following, just to get the correct td element, and I get an exception `object is not set to an instance`.

```
var title = from item in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            where item.Name == "td" && item.Attributes["class"].Value == "title"
            select item.InnerHtml;
```

With this small example, I'll probably figure out the rest of what I need.

Thank you for the suggestions.

```
<tr class="first-in-year">
  <td class="year">2011</td>

  <td class="img"><a href="/battlefield-3/61-27006/"><img src=
  "http://media.giantbomb.com/uploads/6/63038/1700748-bf3_thumb.jpg" alt=""></a></td>

  <td class="title">
    <a href="/battlefield-3/61-27006/">Battlefield 3</a>

    <p class="deck">Battlefield 3 is DICE's next installment in the franchise and
    will be on PC, PS3 and Xbox 360. The game will feature jets, prone, a
    single-player and co-op campaign, and 64-player multiplayer (on PC). It's due out
    in Fall of 2011.</p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using XPath selectors with class or other attribute specifiers.

```
//td[@class='title']/a
```

It should give you all  elements within  elements that have the class 'title'. You would then iterate through that NodeCollection and call the node.InnerText property.

```
  var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title']/a");
  foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes)
  {
     string title = node.InnerText;
  }
```

The tutorial/resource at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) is pretty good for quick ramp up.

Comment: At the end of title, are you missing a apostrophe or is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

XPath should do the trick. Something like this should help:

```
var text = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title']/a");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
string title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//td[@class='title']/a").InnerText;
```